# Create a shared calendar for a group

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-outlook-365

My goal is to create a shared calendar in outlook where our team puts in their holiday and work elsewhere so we can easily see who will be in the office on any particular day. I also want to link this calendar to our Microsoft Teams channel as a Website addon.

My idea is that everyone should be able to create appointments in their own calendar and then we would create a shared calendar that would have permissions to our personal calendars and automatically update the time off.

Then I would find this shared calendar in office 365 online and link it to our Teams channel.

It should be simple enough, but I'm struggling with it.

Comment: What part are you stuck with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is not going to work. You can't have one account automatically pull calendar items from other calenders on the fly.

Either make sure everyone invites that calendar, or even better, make everyone an editor in that calendar and teach everyone to put their appointments in that calendar instead of their own.

If the mailbox attached to that calendar is setup as a primary calendar, people will also get notifications for appointments. This is the way it is done everywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate? So I need to create a new group (or mailbox) with a primary calendar, add all the people there as an editor and write the appointments there?
That means I would have to prefix the meeting items, because otherwise I couldn't tell the people apart, right?

Comment: Yes, basically that. You can also give different people a different color, or use Initials, etc. You can even use multiple calendars for multiple departments, depending on what suits your needs and who really needs to see the appointments.